# How to make list view like window's folder view using javascript and html in express?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

Today, I reported the progress of my project to the mentor.

And then I have new mission.

This is my list view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTbk7.jpg)

I made this using javascript and html. The data is from server node.js and database MySQL.

But, My mentor told me to change it better using list control.

Like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/684je.jpg)

This is folder list's view in windows.

Not table, use list. The languge is also javascript and html.

When I click the title, the list needs to sort.

I just want hint!

Anyone who give me the hint? or Where do I start to study?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you don't seem to confident try googling a bubble sort, this should be a good starting place.

Then decide if you want to change the list as it is or store an array and then reformat once sorted =]

Answer (score -1):

Start using AngularJS for your sorting problem. In angular js, do the sorting using filters. The presentation can be done using html and css